# Check POSIX shared memory object size

Tags: c, posix, shared-memory

Is there any way to check if a file descriptor returned by `shm_open` has been created by current process or existed earlier? Also, after doing so is there any way to check it's size?

This is what I have at the moment:

```
if ((fd = shm_open(SHARED_OBJ_NAME, O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0777)) == -1)
    die(1, "Failed to open shared object");

fd_size = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END);

printf("Shared size: %ld\n", fd_size);

if (fd_size == -1 || fd_size < SHARED_OBJ_SIZE) {
    if (ftruncate(fd, 255) == -1)
        printf("ftruncate failed\n");
    fd_size = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END);
}

printf("Shared size: %ld\n", fd_size);
```

But the problem is that I'm always getting "Shared size: -1" twice, and `ftruncate` doesn't fail only if called right after the object has been created.

Comment: I doubt you can call `lssek()` on what `shm_open()` returned. However you want to add a call to `perror()` in case of getting `-1` from `lseek()` to get details on the failure.

Comment: What do you try to achieve by this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to use `stat()` on the shared memory's name passing in the address of an instance of [`struct stat`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_stat.h.html). If the function succeeded you find the shared memory's size in the structures member `st_size`.

From the [POSIX documentation on `stat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/lstat.html):

> If the named file is a shared memory object, the implementation shall update in the **stat** structure pointed to by the *buf* argument the *st_uid*, *st_gid*, *st_size*, and *st_mode* fields, [...]

---

Also calling `lseek()` on a shared memory descriptor results in unspecified behaviour, so it might lead to the expected result or not, depending on the platform the code is running on. To keep the code portable, do not do this.

From the [POSIX documentation on `lseek()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/lseek.html):

> If fildes refers to a shared memory object, the result of the lseek() function is unspecified.

Comment: Thanks, this works. Do you have any idea if the shared object size has to match the page size? I'm trying to resize it to 255B, but fstat tells me that it's 4096B.

Comment: @wesolyromek As you can only map full pages on most systems, it makes sense for POSIX to allow the size of a shared object to be larger than the size you request it to have.